# SQL - The used select statement have a different number of colums

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm trying to make my first function, it creates without any error, but, when I try to use it it gives me error.

Here's the function -

```
    CREATE FUNCTION isie_kontakti (condition CHAR(3)) 
    RETURNS CHAR(100) 
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE returnthis CHAR(100); 
    SELECT DISTINCT Person.name, Person.lastName, Contacts.mobile, Contacts.email 
    FROM Person JOIN Contacts on Contacts.Person_ID = Person.ID 
    JOIN ParentChild on ParentChild.parentID = Person.ID 
    JOIN ChildGroup ON ChildGroup.Person_ID = ParentChild.childID 
    WHERE ChildGroup.Group_ID = 'condition' INTO returnthis; 
    RETURN returnthis; 
    END//
```

Table schema - http://www.imagesup.net/dm-713886347846.png

Comment: aside from you trying to squeeze multiple fields into one return value, i don't think you should have `'condition'` in quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create your function to return a single column of type `char(100)` yet the `returnthis` item contains quite a few columns.

You need to match up your query and return type.

*How* you do that depends on what you're trying to achieve. It's possibly as simple as just concatenating the columns from the `select` into a single variable, something along the lines of (untested since I don't have my DBMS available at the moment):

```
SELECT Person.name     | ' '
     | Person.lastName | ' '
     | Contacts.mobile | ' '
     | Contacts.email
  FROM ...
```

Comment: Used " SELECT CONCAT(Person.name, Person.lastName, Contacts.mobile, Contacts.email) FROM ..." now it gives error - ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row.